# How can I mapping an enum if it contains the "-" character?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, exception, enums, mapping

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wggqI.png)I can't mapping enum in my entity class Film
Class Film:

```
@Column(name = "rating", nullable = false)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private Rating rating;
```

Exception

```
Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [rating] in table [movie.film]; found [enum (Types#CHAR)], but expecting [integer (Types#INTEGER)]
```

Enum

```
public enum Rating {
    G,
    PG,
    PG_13,
    R,
    NC_17
}
```

SQL table Film
ENUM('G', 'PG', 'PG_13', 'R', 'NC_17')

I tried changing "-" to "_" in enum
I tried changing annotations, it doesn't help

Comment: If you have to allow characters, in your rating column of the movie.film table you should use varchar instead of integer.